# Referencing a .Net 4.0 Assembly in the GAC from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, gac

Has anyone done this?

I have created an assembly and installed it to the GAC.  It's listed in gacutil and I can see it in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly folder.

I have found people saying to add registry keys, but the folders they specify don't exist, and when I create them, my assembly is still not appearing in the list.

I have tried Muse VSExtensions but it doesn't find the assembly either, I don't think it picks up the .net 4 assembly folder.

I have managed to add a reference to my assembly by manually editing the project file to add the reference. This worked fine but is far from ideal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi HermanTheSheep,

Muse VSExtensions should be able to find your .NET 4 assembly. Is there any specific with your assembly. If the problem still persist could you give me more details, or send me an assembly that has this particular problem and I'll fix it for you

muse.vsextensions@live.com

Thanks...

Muse Extension

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see it in the add referances dialog you only need to install the file into the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
```

then people can add referances from there and you do not need to worry about the GAC or the registry.